# Transferring memory between processes

Tags: rust

I want to transfer an item between processes (specifically a [TcpStream](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html)). I attempted to do this with a more complex example however failed in this. So I am trying to do this with a simpler example:

My current attempt is:

```rust
use bytes::{Buf, BytesMut};
use tokio::{
    io::AsyncWriteExt,
    net::{tcp::OwnedWriteHalf, TcpListener, TcpStream},
};
use tokio_stream::StreamExt;
use tokio_util::codec::{Decoder, FramedRead};

const TRANSFER_ADDRESS: &str = "127.0.0.1:8081";
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    if let Ok(existing_server_process_listener) =
        TcpStream::connect(TRANSFER_ADDRESS).await
    {
        let (read, _write) = existing_server_process_listener.into_split();
        let mut reader = FramedRead::new(read, DatabaseTransferDecoder);
        let bytes = reader.next().await.unwrap().unwrap();
        dbg!(&bytes);
        let addr = usize::from_ne_bytes(bytes.try_into().unwrap());
        dbg!(addr);
        let ptr = addr as *mut u32;
        dbg!(ptr);
        let box_ptr = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr)};
        dbg!(box_ptr);
    }
    else {
        let update_listener = TcpListener::bind(TRANSFER_ADDRESS).await.unwrap();
        let (stream, _socket) = update_listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        // Splits our stream into read/write
        let (_read, mut write) = stream.into_split();
        let x = Box::new(4u32);
        let ptr = Box::into_raw(x);
        dbg!(ptr);
        let addr = ptr as usize;
        dbg!(addr);
        let bytes = addr.to_ne_bytes();
        dbg!(bytes);
        write_fn(&mut write,&bytes).await;
    }
    
}

async fn write_fn(writer: &mut OwnedWriteHalf, string: &[u8]) {
    let buffer = {
        let mut b = Vec::with_capacity(4 + string.len());
        b.extend_from_slice(&u32::to_le_bytes(u32::try_from(string.len()).unwrap()));
        b.extend_from_slice(string);
        b
    };
    writer.write_all(&buffer).await.unwrap();
}

struct DatabaseTransferDecoder;
/// Implement `tokio_util::codec::decoder` for framed reads.
impl Decoder for DatabaseTransferDecoder {
    type Error = std::io::Error;
    type Item = Vec<u8>;

    fn decode(&mut self, src: &mut BytesMut) -> Result<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        // We use u32 for len marker, so need an initial 4 bytes
        if src.len() < 4 {
            return Ok(None);
        }
        // Get length
        let length = {
            let mut length_bytes = [0; 4];
            length_bytes.copy_from_slice(&src[..4]);
            u32::from_le_bytes(length_bytes) as usize
        };
        if src.len() < 4 + length {
            src.reserve(4 + length - src.len());
            return Ok(None);
        }
        // Read data
        let data = src[4..4 + length].to_vec();
        // Advance buffer to discard data
        src.advance(4 + length);
        Ok(Some(data))
    }
}
```

Running the first process then running the second process causes the first process to output:

```
[src\main.rs:33] ptr = 0x000001f8b8435980
[src\main.rs:35] addr = 2167754938752
[src\main.rs:37] bytes = [
    128,
    89,
    67,
    184,
    248,
    1,
    0,
    0,
]
```

and the second process to output:

```
[src\main.rs:18] &bytes = [
    128,
    89,
    67,
    184,
    248,
    1,
    0,
    0,
]
[src\main.rs:20] addr = 2167754938752
[src\main.rs:22] ptr = 0x000001f8b8435980
[src\main.rs:24] box_ptr = error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\testing-bin.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
```

Why would accessing this memory cause this error?

Comment: It is outside of its address space. Accessing a shared memory is not easy. You're probably looking for [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), though there may be easier ways such as transferring the data with sockets.

Comment: I've added more to my question which may clarify the use case better.

Comment: You need to send the *data* over the tcp stream that you want to send to the other process. Sending just the address doesn't work since distinct processes cannot access each other's memory. You would *serialize* your item, send the bytes, and then *deserialize* it on the other end.

Comment: @kmdreko I know you can share memory between processes, in essence I am asking how in this context.

Comment: You can use *shared memory* by which you tell the OS to provide a region of memory that is accessible to both processes. There are [crates](https://crates.io/search?q=shared%20memory) that can help you with that.

Comment: Note however that `TcpStream` contains a file descriptor which can't be shared with another process even with shared memory.